# How do I open a file in Perl using a search path (e.g. $PATH)?

Tags: perl

I have a situation in which I am reading filenames from a file in Perl. These filenames **never** have a directory associated with them, only a file name (e.g. "foo.bar"). I need to search the equivalent of `gmake`'s VPATH (or a shell's PATH) for that file.

I figure I can split the PATH at the colons, concatenate each segment to the file, and see if it exists. Is there an easier way to do this, though?

Comment: In this case, actually, it will be a list passed in from `gmake`, not an environment variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's so uneasy in it?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw{ first };

sub find_in_path {
    my $file = shift;
    return first { -f } map "$_/$file", split /:/, $ENV{PATH}
}

print find_in_path('grep'), "\n";
```

Comment: Portable solution 1: `use Config qw( %Config ); return first { -f } map "$_/$file", split quotemeta($Config{path_sep}), $ENV{PATH};`

Comment: Portable solution 2: `use Env qw( @PATH ); return first { -f } map "$_/$file", @PATH;`

Comment: That **is** easy, had I known about `List::Util` and understood `map` better. (I wish there were a list & documentation on all the available modules. Or perhaps I should say I wish I knew how to find them.)